# How to read property from nested JSON in C# using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, nested, json.net, webclient

So here is my problem, I am using CoinMarketCap's api to get cryptocurrency information for my app. The problem is that I am not able to read the properties from the JSON. I am trying to get the current crypto price. I feel like I'm close, I managed to cast the whole thing to JSON and access the first nested data, however afterwards it's not a JObject anymore, but a JArray, so I can't simply access properties by name I believe.

Here is the actual code:

```
public static string GetCryptoUnitValue(string coinSymbol)
    {
        var URL = new UriBuilder("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest");

        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        queryString["symbol"] = coinSymbol;
        queryString["convert"] = "USD";

        URL.Query = queryString.ToString();

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", API_KEY);
        client.Headers.Add("Accepts", "application/json");

        string cryptoData = client.DownloadString(URL.ToString());

        JObject json = JObject.Parse(cryptoData);
        var data = (JObject)json["data"];
        var cryptoCurrency = (JObject)data[coinSymbol];
        var quote = cryptoCurrency["quote"];
        var usd = (JObject)quote["USD"];
        var price = (double)usd["price"];
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(price));

        return Convert.ToString(price);
    }
```

The error I get when I get the line "var cryptoCurrency = (JObject)data[coinSymbol];" is the following one:
**System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.'**

Lets say the parameter "coinSymbol" for the example is equal to "BTC", this would be the JSON I get:

```
    {{
  "status": {
    "timestamp": "2023-07-12T17:08:49.341Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 31,
    "credit_count": 1,
    "notice": null
  },
  "data": {
    "BTC": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "num_market_pairs": 10341,
        "date_added": "2010-07-13T00:00:00Z",
        "tags": [
          {
            "slug": "mineable",
            "name": "Mineable",
            "category": "OTHERS"
          }
        ],
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "circulating_supply": 19427587,
        "total_supply": 19427587,
        "is_active": 1,
        "infinite_supply": false,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 1,
        "is_fiat": 0,
        "self_reported_circulating_supply": null,
        "self_reported_market_cap": null,
        "tvl_ratio": null,
        "last_updated": "2023-07-12T17:07:00Z",
        "quote": {
          "USD": {
            "price": 30500.58272538358,
            "volume_24h": 14011375945.039093,
            "volume_change_24h": -10.7739,
            "percent_change_1h": 0.09624256,
            "percent_change_24h": -0.47967662,
            "percent_change_7d": 0.03734603,
            "percent_change_30d": 18.12871397,
            "percent_change_60d": 13.72165636,
            "percent_change_90d": 0.49714266,
            "market_cap": 592552724448.0867,
            "market_cap_dominance": 49.8913,
            "fully_diluted_market_cap": 640512237233.06,
            "tvl": null,
            "last_updated": "2023-07-12T17:07:00Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}}
```

Here is everything I tried to be able to read properties of a nested JSON in C#:

1. [Retrieving value from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338659/retrieving-value-from-a-json-string)
2. [Reading and Writing Nested data JSON in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622410/reading-and-writing-nested-data-json-in-c-sharp)
3. [Deserialize Nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844837/deserialize-nested-json)
4. [Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495634/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-newtonsoft-json-linq-jobject-to-type-newtonsoft)
5. [Retrieve required string from bigger JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531441/retrieve-required-string-from-bigger-json-string)
6. https://github.com/lzehrung/coinmarketcap/tree/master
7. https://code-maze.com/csharp-get-value-by-key-from-jobject/
8. [How to get a JSON string from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566942/how-to-get-a-json-string-from-url)
9. And more that I lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON value is an array, but you're casting it as if it's not.

Try this to get the first element of the array:

```
var cryptoCurrency = ((JArray)data[coinSymbol])[0];
```